# while building using ant tool iam getting below error

Tags: ant, izpack

Iam getting below error while building using ant tool

```
installer.izpack.exe:
     [exec] Traceback (most recent call last):
     [exec]   File "C:\PROGRA~1\IzPack/utils/wrappers/izpack2exe/izpack2exe.py", line 126, in <module>
     [exec]     main()
     [exec]   File "C:\PROGRA~1\IzPack/utils/wrappers/izpack2exe/izpack2exe.py", line 123, in main
     [exec]     create_exe(parse_options())
     [exec]   File "C:\PROGRA~1\IzPack/utils/wrappers/izpack2exe/izpack2exe.py", line 77, in create_exe
     [exec]     subprocess.call(p7zcmd, shell=use_shell)
     [exec]   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
     [exec]     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
     [exec]   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
     [exec]     errread, errwrite)
     [exec]   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
     [exec]     startupinfo)
     [exec] WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

BUILD FAILED
E:\Java Projects\Spark Projects\EastIT - Copy\build\build.xml:873: exec returned: 1
```

Below is code at which getting error.

```
<target name="installer.izpack.exe" depends="installer.izpack" description="build release executable izpack installer">
        <exec executable="python" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="${installer.izpack.dir}/utils/wrappers/izpack2exe/izpack2exe.py"/>
            <arg line="--file=${basedir}/installer/EasyIT-installer.jar"/>
            <arg line="--output=${basedir}/installer/EasyIT-installer.exe"/>
            <arg line="--no-upx"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

please can anyone figureout how to resolve this?

Comment: Does the same command run from the command-line? Does not look to me like an ANT issue.

Comment: ya the same command runs on the command-line

Comment: similar problem, with an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538671/python-call-to-external-program-results-in-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-a

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running the izpack2exe.py script manually on a Windows 7 x64 machine. I made some adjustments to the python script, which now looks as follows:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import shutil
import optparse
import shlex

def parse_options():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--file", action="append", dest="file",
                      help="The installer JAR file / files")
    parser.add_option("--output", action="store", dest="output",
                      default="setup.exe",
                      help="The executable file")
    parser.add_option("--with-jdk", action="store", dest="with_jre", default="",
      help="The bundled JRE to run the exe independently of the system resources. ")  # choosen JDK that may came with the package
    parser.add_option("--with-7z", action="store", dest="p7z",
                      default="7za",
                      help="Path to the 7-Zip executable")
    parser.add_option("--with-upx", action="store", dest="upx",
                      default="upx",
                      help="Path to the UPX executable")
    parser.add_option("--no-upx", action="store_true", dest="no_upx",
                      default=False,
                      help="Do not use UPX to further compress the output")
    parser.add_option("--launch-file", action="store", dest="launch",
                      default="",
                      help="File to launch after extract")
    parser.add_option("--launch-args", action="store", dest="launchargs",
                      default="",
                      help="Arguments for file to launch after extract")
    parser.add_option("--name", action="store", dest="name",
                      default="IzPack",
                      help="Name of package for title bar and prompts")
    parser.add_option("--prompt", action="store_true", dest="prompt",
                      default=False,
                      help="Prompt the user before extraction?")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if (options.file is None):
        parser.error("no installer file has been given")
    return options

def create_exe(settings):
    if len(settings.file) > 0:
        filename = os.path.basename(settings.file[0])
    else:
        filename = ''

    if len(settings.with_jre) > 0:
        jdk = os.path.basename(settings.with_jre) #inside the jdk/jre that was given, there must be a bin/java.exe file
        jdk = jdk + "\\bin\\javaw.exe"
        print(jdk)
        settings.file.append(settings.with_jre) #jdk/jre is going in the package
    else:
        jdk = 'javaw' #java is added somehow to the PATH

    if settings.p7z == '7za':
        p7z = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), '7za')
    else:
        p7z = settings.p7z

    # really no need right now
    # use_shell = sys.platform != 'win32'

    if (os.access('installer.7z', os.F_OK)):
        os.remove('installer.7z')
    files = '" "'.join(settings.file)
    p7zcmd = '7za.exe a -mmt -t7z -mx=9 installer.7z "%s"' % files
    zip_proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(p7zcmd))
    zip_proc.communicate()

    config = open('config.txt', 'w')
    config.write(';!@Install@!UTF-8!\n')
    config.write('Title="%s"\n' % settings.name)
    if settings.prompt:
        config.write('BeginPrompt="Install %s?"\n' % settings.name)
    config.write('Progress="yes"\n')

    if settings.launch == '':
        config.write('ExecuteFile="' + jdk + '"\n') # who is going to run my installer.jar?
        config.write('ExecuteParameters="-jar \\\"%s\\\"' % filename)
        if settings.launchargs != '':
            config.write(' %s"\n' % settings.launchargs)
        else:
            config.write('"\n') 
    else:
        config.write('ExecuteFile="%s"\n' % settings.launch)
        if settings.launchargs != '':
            config.write('ExecuteParameters="%s"\n' % settings.launchargs)

    config.write(';!@InstallEnd@!\n')
    config.close()

    sfx = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(p7z), '7zS.sfx')
    files = [sfx, 'config.txt', 'installer.7z']

    output = open(settings.output, 'wb')
    for f in files:
        in_file = open(f, 'rb')
        shutil.copyfileobj(in_file, output, 2048)
        in_file.close()
    output.close()

    if (not settings.no_upx):
        if settings.upx == 'upx':
            upx = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), 'upx')
        else:
            upx = settings.upx
        upx = 'upx.exe --ultra-brute "%s"' % settings.output
        upx_proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(upx))
        upx_proc.communicate()

    os.remove('config.txt')
    os.remove('installer.7z')

def main():
    create_exe(parse_options())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I statically put the 7za.exe in the p7zcmd variable which doesn't result in problems as it is on my path. I blocked the script execution until the subprocesses where done (7zip and upx respectively) which resolved my problems.

Hope I could help you.

Regards