# WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application in Python

Tags: python, 64-bit, runtime-error, pyscripter

I wish to import [liblas](http://www.liblas.org/tutorial/python.html) module in Python 2.7 on window 64bit. If I import the module with IDLE (Python GUI) I have no problem.

If I use [PyScripter](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/downloads/detail?name=PyScripter-v2.5.3-x64-Setup.exe&can=2&q=) "PyScripter-v2.5.3-x64-Setup.exe" I get this error message.

```
>>> import liblas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\liblas\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from core import get_version
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\liblas\core.py", line 138, in <module>
    las = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(local_dlls, lib_name))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I have used liblas in PyScripter many times without problem and right now I can load all standard modules (e.g.: numpy, GDAL, etc.), but tonight (I need to finish an analysis!!!) I have this inconvenience.

Comment: fist i have always a problem windowsError. Second, it's not a problem of liblas but a Pyscript problem. I can imprt liblas in IDLE of Python  without problem (as i wrote). But thanks for the try

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure to have Python 2.7 64b edition :) or even though you are working on 64b OS, use the x86 (AKA 32b) edition of PyScripter

**Edit 1 (following comments exchange w/ Gianni)**

One should verify his/her *entire* Python process "composed" from same entities in the sense of 32b/64b builds (e.g. if your Python interpreter is 32b one, then it must use C types coming from C dll  Python extensions which were compiled as 32b dlls).

In our example (liblas) one should go to `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\liblas` , find the extension dll and see its type via [dumpbin](http://www.mohid.com/wiki/index.php?title=Dumpbin) , here is some picture for demonstration :

[image]

Comment: i am super sure to have Python 2.7.3 64 bit. If i install PyScripter-v2.5.3-Setup.exe i cannot run Python

Comment: @Gianni , please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538671/python-call-to-external-program-results-in-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-a , I think libals backend dll is a 32b one, so maybe using Python 32b will mitigate the issue

Comment: I suppose in Win64, a 64-bit process must be all 64-bit

Comment: i can run liblas in Python IDLE without problem. I have liblas on other 64bit PC and i can run with pyscript without problem. I had run for months liblas without problems

Comment: This is exactly my point, maybe the libals dll is a 32b module after all (you can verify it via the usage of dumpbin or dependency walker)

Comment: could you explain i can verify it via the usage of dumpbin? thanks

Comment: @Gianni I've updated my answer w/ more information (sorry for my late response)

Answer (score 2):

This error can also be caused because the DLL that Python is attempting to run has been compiled on a newer version of C++.  Make sure you are running the latest version of the Microsoft C++ Distribution.

You can see the version you are running in the Python terminal window (highlighted in bold)

Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [**MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)**] on win32

Download here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using 64 bits Python.
You should install the **32 bits** version instead.

Comment: is not that. ive tried 64 and 32 and both didnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error too, plase take a look at your python.exe file.

In my case it was corrupted as you can see below:

[image]

So I copied from another venv and reinstalled the dependencies.

Then it worked :)