# Failed import lib Scrypt in Python

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32, scrypt

When I try to import the Scrypt lib from Python right after I'd instaled the package using pip the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrypt.py", line 11, in <module>
    _scrypt = cdll.LoadLibrary(imp.find_module('_scrypt')[1])
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 nÒo Ú um aplicativo Win32 vßlido
```

In English the message "WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 nÒo Ú um aplicativo Win32 vßlido" means that it is not a valid win32 application

In another computer, when i try to import the same lib there's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrypt.py", line 11, in <module>
    _scrypt = cdll.LoadLibrary(imp.find_module('_scrypt')[1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 440, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 126] NÒo foi possÝvel encontrar o m¾dulo especificado
```

In English the message "NÒo foi possÝvel encontrar o m¾dulo especificado" means that was not possible find the module

Comment: Take a look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374710/windowserror-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-in-python) and make sure the process isn't trying to open a 64bit file as a 32bit one.

Comment: I was looking for someone who had the same problem that I have, in all cases they were using or the lib or Python in different architectures, but I'm using both 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `OpenSSL` will fix your problem on windows, here in the [Link](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).