# Python error while opening other files

Tags: python

```
import os
var = 'x=msgbox("File could not be found." & vbNewLine & "Remove windows?", 0+16, "DAM")'
f=open("error.vbs", "w")
f.write(var)
f.close()
os.system('error.vbs')
```

I have this code, but it doesn't run error.vbs after I create it. How might I fix this?

Comment: Is your `error.vbs` script executable? What does `os.stat('error.vbs')` return? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791997/how-do-you-do-a-simple-chmod-x-from-within-python) might help.

Comment: `error.vbs` does not seem to be executable.

Comment: How would I fix this? I've tried    os.start('error.vbs')

Comment: Related question: [Executing a vbs file with arguments created by python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112944/executing-a-vbs-file-with-arguments-created-by-python)