# Python 3.6 trying to use commands from another program

Tags: python, python-3.6

Part of my python program uses subprocess to open a vbs script.

```
path = os.sep.join(['C:','Users',getpass.getuser(),'Desktop','Program','build','exe.win32-3.6','vbs.vbs'])

subprocess.call([sys.executable, path])
```

But instead of executing my vbs script it tries to run it as a python code and gives me: NameError: msgbox is not defined.
And when i manually run vbs script it works.

I want python to normally execute the vbs script. Not run it as python code.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: `sys.executable` is the Python interpreter. Use the name of the executable you want to run the `.vbs` file with instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a vbs file with arguments created by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112944/executing-a-vbs-file-with-arguments-created-by-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.executable` points to the system's Python executable. In your case that'd probably be something like `C:\Python27\python.exe`. You should print it out and see for yourself.

To execute VBScripts, you'd want to use `C:\Windows\system32\wscript.exe`.

Additionally, using `os.path.join()` is more suited to the task than `os.sep.join()`.

So you'd end up with:

```
system32 = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], 'system32')
wscript = os.path.join(system32, 'wscript.exe')
path = os.sep.join(['C:','Users',getpass.getuser(),'Desktop','Program','build','exe.win32-3.6','vbs.vbs'])
subprocess.call([wscript, path])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is *exactly what you are telling subprocess to do*. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable)

> **sys.executable**
>
> A string giving the absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense. If Python is
>   unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, `sys.executable`
>   will be an empty string or `None`.