# Call vbscript from python

Tags: python, vbscript

I'm trying to invoke a vbscript through python as follows

```
import os
import sys 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rancsv = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(150, 5))
rancsv.to_csv('randomcsv.csv', sep=',')
os.system(r"C:\Users\v-2mo\Documents\Python Scripts\test.vbs")
```

However this simply gives an output of 1 in jupyter notebook and does not run the script.

The script when run directly, runs just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call it through either `wscript.exe` *(Windows GUI)* or `cscript.exe` *(Command line)* host applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system(r"C:\\Users\\v-2mo\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\test.vbs")
```

or

```
os.system(r"C:/Users/v-2mo/Documents/Python Scripts/test.vbs")
```

Comment: Doesn't the `r` prefix mean that you can write \ instead of \\ in your first snippet?

Answer (score 0):

answered well here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19114284/17889328
in short, .vbs opens ok in command prompt because shell associates with program wscriipt or cscript and runs it. run silently your program doesn't get the associationand doesn't know how to open. need specify "wscript filename.vbs"  and / or run with shell eg "cmd /c..."