# Is it possible to call a macro of notepad++ from python?

Tags: python-3.x, notepad++

I have a macro that make changes to all files in a folder in notepad++ but I am trying to automatizate the process with a python code but I do not find any solution for this. Maybe I can use the shortcuts.xml in some way but I am totally lost.

This is my final solution if someone needs it, you MUST set your macro to a shortcut, in this case 'ctr+alt+9' (comments are on spanish):

```
#
# Es necesario instalar las bibliotecas
# pip install pyautogui
# pip install pywin32
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# Version: 1.3
# Date: 10/07/2019
# 
# Resumen: Pone Notepad++ como pantalla activa y pulsa ctrl+alt+9
# y acepta los pop ups de la macro
#
# Autor: Pedro Antonio Fondevila Franco
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
import pyautogui
import win32gui
import win32con
import time


# Copiado de Stackoverflow, retorna lista de las ventanas activas
# stackoverflow.com/questions/16770909/python-win32gui-setforegroundwindow

def window_enum_handler(hwnd, resultList):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) != '':
        resultList.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

def get_app_list(handles=[]):
    mlst=[]
    win32gui.EnumWindows(window_enum_handler, handles)
    for handle in handles:
        mlst.append(handle)
    return mlst

appwindows = get_app_list()
# ---------------------------------------------------------------- 

targetWindow = 0;
for window in appwindows:# Buscamos si notepad++ esta en la lista
    if ("Notepad++" in window[1]): 
        targetWindow = window[0]

if(targetWindow != 0): 

    win32gui.ShowWindow(targetWindow,win32con.SW_RESTORE) # Por si esta minimizada la pantalla
    win32gui.BringWindowToTop(targetWindow) # La ponemos delante
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(targetWindow) # La ponemos como ventana principal

    time.sleep(0.4) # Le damos tiempo a cambiar al notepad++
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'alt', '9') # Pulsa ctrl+alt+9

    numberOfPopUps = 10
    for i in range(1, numberOfPopUps + 1):  
        time.sleep(0.4)
        pyautogui.press('left') # Pulsa izquierda
        pyautogui.press('enter') # Pulsa enter
else: 
    print("Inicie Notepad++")
    time.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: Did you check `xlwings` library?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Why don't you run Python script directly without using Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use VBScript or PowerShell and Python in combination for your needs.

At Notepad++ Community is a thread [How to run a notepad++ macro from vbscript or PowerShell](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14437/how-to-run-a-notepad-macro-from-vbscript-or-powershell).

Quoted from Yaron's answer:

```
objShell.run …
' Let NPP load and open the file. Adjust the number of milliseconds to your machine.
WScript.Sleep(100)
' "^+9" is Ctrl+Shift+9. Replace it with your preferred shortcut.          
objShell.SendKeys("^+9")
```

1. Assign a shortcut to your macro via Settings -> Shortcut Mapper ->
   Macros.
2. Add the above lines to the script.

You'll find a possible solution for the second part [Executing a vbs file with arguments created by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112944/executing-a-vbs-file-with-arguments-created-by-python) on SO here.