# Location of File suppressing error.'error 193'

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I am getting the error

```
 WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

on my console when i am running the command

```
python triaging_flow.py
```

from Desktop.

But at the same time when **i copy the same .py file to a random folder** which i created and **executing the same command** in the new directory from console, **it is running**.

```
   File "triaging_flow.py", line 107, in <module>
    browser=webdriver.Chrome();
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
self.service.start()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.48.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.py", line 66, in start
self.service_args, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
```

I followed up on few instances similar to this :
[python Call to external program results in [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538671/python-call-to-external-program-results-in-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-a)

And found that it is not a versioning issue. I am guessing it might be a environment variable path issue.

Path specified is:

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue? Any heads up regarding this would be great.

**PS**: I can continue my work by pasting the file in a folder but wanted to know if there is any specific reason for this issue.

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: What is the result of the command 'where python' when you are in Desktop?